# Treeview Instead of listbox in AutoCompleteBox Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, autocomplete, treeview

I need an AutoCompleteBox that this will show results in a TreeView according to their parents.
This operation does not need to be dynamic. The only requirement is, that the user should be able to see AutoCompleteBox pop-up results with their parents like a tree.

Is there any way to implement this kind of component or any ready component for this?

Comment: Possible! but what did you try so far?

Comment: I found nothing about this topic.I need a sample or instructions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a Treeview Inside the AutoCompleteBox,

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" AllowDrop="True"   ItemsSource="{Binding}"   x:Name="txtMain"  Height="25">
                <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate> 
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <sdk:TreeView   ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" Name="treeView1">
                            <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property}" />
                                    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        </sdk:TreeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            </sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: This works but how can make this to query child nodes?This only finds nodes that in the list wihich i assigned to ItemsSource.But i have more nodes in parents'.

Comment: @mekafe can you give me +1, also check this link to find the nodes http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36193/WPF-TreeView-tools